# What is the correct way to get screen width/height with orientation changes?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm currently using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width` and height to get the screen width and height for getting a new image (that fills the screen) from a server.  My problem is it appears that the bounds doesn't change on orientation changes.  So if I rotate the device then it still gives me portrait width/heights even though the device is now in landscape. I'd like to not hardcode a screen width/height based on the current orientation.  Is there a way that I can check the screen width and height that will correctly reflect orientation changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the width and height by

```
int h = self.view.frame.size.height;
int w = self.view.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: Most simple solution and it works great, only thing is it's self.view.frame.size.width and height.

Comment: Note this will not give you the *screen* bounds if your view controller is inside a UITabBarController, UINavigationController, UISplitViewController, or the like.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is probably:

```
CGSize appSize = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view.bounds.size;
```

and also use `appSize.height` for height and `appSize.width` for width
This returns the orientation adjusted size of the topmost view which always fills the full screen, except possibly excluding the status bar depending on your status bar and wantsFullscreen settings.

Answer (score 0):

`[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size` returns the bounds unrotated. You can use the [`convertRect:fromView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDBGGG) method (passing nil for the fromView) on an appropriate on-screen UIView to adjust for rotation and such.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on an app where we have run into problems like this on a few occasions, so I hope I can help:

1. First off, make sure you are using a `UIViewController` to manage your image.
2. Secondly, make sure your implementation of `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` on that view controller returns `YES`.
3. Make sure you are using a `UIImageView`, not a `UIImage` for your picture, then try setting `autoresizesSubviews` on the image view's *superview* (this is the view controller's view) to `YES`.
4. If the image resizes, but not to your liking, try messing with the image view's `autoresizingMask`.
5. If, after step 3, the image doesn't autoresize, try implementing `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and programmatically setting the image's frame.  Remember that it's superview (the `UIViewController's` view) hasn't rotated yet, so its frame hasn't updated.
6. Finally, if that doesn't work, try `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, though I'm not quite clear on the difference between this method and the former.

Hope this helps, and let me know your results!

-Bruce

Answer (score 0):

try get your height and width from applicationFrame

> UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size.height